# JavaScript zoom image to mouse cursor compatible with IE

Tags: javascript, image, zooming

I need to zoom an image to the mouse cursor using JavaScript. The problem is, all info I found on how to do this is using CSS3 transforms, etc. It needs to be cross-browser compatible and as far as I know, IE 7 (I think even up to 9) isn't compatible with CSS3.

Is there any way I can do this with jQuery or pure JavaScript? Right now, I made it zoom with the mousewheel, but that's the easy part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/02/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-stunning-image-zoom-effects.html

Probably want the 3rd one down.

Comment: Not exaclty what i need, but i think i'll have to take that and try to modify it myself. If i get it done, i'll post it. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery Kabbar image zoomer is crossbrowser compatible:

http://www.ideabonus.com/Kabbar/index.html